# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," react

Tags: reactjs

Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

13 |     setPosts(snapshot.docs.map((doc)=>({id: doc.id, data: doc.data() })))
14 |     )

> 15 |   },[]);
> |   ^
> 16 |
> 17 |   return (
> 18 |

```
 useEffect(() =>{
 db.collection['posts'].onSnapshot(snapshot =>(
 setPosts(snapshot.docs.map((doc)=>({id: doc.id, data: doc.data() })))
  )
 },[]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
useEffect(() => {
    db.collection['posts'].onSnapshot(snapshot => (
        setPosts(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data() })))
    ));
}, []);
```